# Why can't set variables related collation as utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Tags: mariadb, collation

Show mysql version here:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

And my mariadb's configuration file.

```
cat   /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysqld]

character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init_connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
init_connect = 'SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci'


[client-server]
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Enter into mysql,issue command `show variables like 'collation%';`:

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

How can get the below result?

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Log in with a normal user `showkey`.

```
debian@debian:~$ mysql -u showkey -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 31
Server version: 10.5.11-MariaDB-1 Debian 11

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Connection collation solution 1

In the `[client]` option group of your .cnf files you can set:

```
init_command = "SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

If you want the same connection collation in PHP or some other programming language, then you will need to set that in its config or code as well. E.g. for PHP you can do something like:

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci");
```

#### Connection collation solution 2

In the `[mysqld]` option group, simply add the following line:

```
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

I believe this will force all clients to use the character set and collation of the server. This has the advantage that the client doesn't (need to) send a SET command for every connection, i.e. less time is spent waiting before the connection is ready, and less work for the server.

#### Database collation

Then, to set the collation for the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE test 
  CHARACTER SET = 'utf8mb4' 
  COLLATE = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

#### Server collation

And for the server setting, you can do that dynamically within the mysql CLI:

```
SET character_set_server = utf8mb4;
SET collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Use the `GLOBAL` keyword to set it globally for all new connections (until server restart):

```
SET GLOBAL character_set_server = utf8mb4;
SET GLOBAL collation_server = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

Or you can instead set it in the `[mysqld]` option group in your .cnf files (if so, restart the server afterwards for it to take effect):

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

#### Result

This should give you:

```
MariaDB [test]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

The documentation for this is found in the MariaDB.com Knowledgebase:

- [Setting Character Sets and Collations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/)
- [SET NAMES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-names/): This explains that `SET NAMES` implicitly sets the collation_connection.
- [mysql CLI](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql-command-line-client/) Mentions the init-command

Answer (score 1):

`init_connect` is ignored when connecting as `root`.

Don't use `root` except for admin purposes; have different login(s) for applications and users.

Comment: Same output when  to log in with a normal user.It is not the reason in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines in `my.cnf` & restart MySQL instance :

```
[mysqld]
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character_set_server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Then you check it :

```
mysql> select @@collation_connection;
+------------------------+
| @@collation_connection |
+------------------------+
| utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: That is what I already said in my answer ...

Comment: Yeah, dear that answer was sort of confusing also you mentioned to set collation from client connection which is not proper to set everytime. So, This only line can solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47566730/force-mariadb-clients-to-use-utf8mb4

It suggests to use:

```
init_connect = "SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```